# ls hangs on NAS mount point

Tags: linux, unix, network-attached-storage, rhel6

Frequently we are running into this problem.

our NAS mount points works perfectly and all of sudden it hangs.

when we go and do ls hangs the terminal.

strace ls /srv/git

hangs here

```
 unmap(0x7f6a5c03f000, 4096)            = 0
 open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 3
 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=99158576, ...}) = 0
 mmap(NULL, 99158576, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6a5619e000
 close(3)                                = 0
 ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo      ...}) = 0
 ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=28, ws_col=117, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
 stat("/srv/git",

^C <unfinished ...>
```

ps -ef | grep ls

gives us lots of such process

```
 user1    9099  9050  0 05:39 pts/7    00:00:00 ls --color=auto
 user1    9165     1  0 05:42 pts/8    00:00:00 ls /srv/git
 user1    9168     1  0 05:42 pts/8    00:00:00 ls /srv/git
 user1    9235  9111  0 05:47 pts/8    00:00:00 grep ls
 gt       40490 40483  0 Apr15 ?        00:00:00 ls -1 /srv/git/mirrors
```

dmesg

```
   Call Trace:
      [<ffffffffa026f36e>] ? rpc_make_runnable+0x7e/0x80 [sunrpc]
      [<ffffffffa026fc10>] ? rpc_execute+0x50/0xa0 [sunrpc]
      [<ffffffff810aaa21>] ? ktime_get_ts+0xb1/0xf0
      [<ffffffff811242d0>] ? sync_page+0x0/0x50
      [<ffffffff8152a1b3>] io_schedule+0x73/0xc0
      [<ffffffff8112430d>] sync_page+0x3d/0x50
      [<ffffffff8152ac7f>] __wait_on_bit+0x5f/0x90
      [<ffffffff81124543>] wait_on_page_bit+0x73/0x80
      [<ffffffff8109eb80>] ? wake_bit_function+0x0/0x50
      [<ffffffff8113a525>] ? pagevec_lookup_tag+0x25/0x40
      [<ffffffff8112496b>] wait_on_page_writeback_range+0xfb/0x190
      [<ffffffff81139651>] ? do_writepages+0x21/0x40
      [<ffffffff81124abb>] ? __filemap_fdatawrite_range+0x5b/0x60
      [<ffffffff81124b38>] filemap_write_and_wait_range+0x78/0x90
      [<ffffffff811c07ce>] vfs_fsync_range+0x7e/0x100
      [<ffffffff811c08bd>] vfs_fsync+0x1d/0x20
      [<ffffffffa030c930>] nfs_file_flush+0x70/0xa0 [nfs]
      [<ffffffff8118ac4c>] filp_close+0x3c/0x90
      [<ffffffff8118ad45>] sys_close+0xa5/0x100
      [<ffffffff8100b072>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```